# WebAPI Get() method to return list of all records matching criteria

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am a complete noob when it comes to WebAPI/MVC/Entity Framework, so have followed the tutorial at the bottom of this question to create an ASP.NET WebAPI that links to an SQL Server and displays data from a table called ItemDetail.

My ItemDetailController.cs appears as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemDetail> Get()
{
    using (myDBEntities entities = new myDBEntities())
    {
        return entities.ItemDetail.ToList();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<ItemDetail> Get(int id)
{
    using (myDBEntities entities = new myDBEntities())
    {
        yield return entities.ItemDetail.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ItemDetailID == id);
    }
}
```

**What it currently does**

1. Get() returns all results in the ItemDetail table.
2. Get(int id) returns a single result from the ItemDetail table where the ID matches the parameter.

**What I'd like it to do**

I would like to have a third Get() method that returns all records from the ItemDetail table that are in a particular department e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<ItemDetail> Get(string departmentName)
{
    using (myDBEntities entities = new myDBEntities())
    {
        return entities.ItemDetail.ToList(e => e.DeptName== departmentName);
    }
}
```

but this results in the following error:

> No overload for method 'ToList' takes 1 argument

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

**Tutorial used**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-and-sql-server/.

Comment: `return entities.ItemDetail.Where(e => e.DeptName == departmentName).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen Muecke said

```
return entities.ItemDetail.Where(e => e.DeptName == departmentName).ToList();
```

(never quite figured out why people put answers as comments)

Your "get single" could also be written as:

```
yield return entities.ItemDetail.Where(e => e.ItemDetailID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Putting the `Where` clause into the `FirstOrDefaul`t is a feature `FirstOrDefault` offers, that `ToList` doesn't.